# Tabular Parent-Child Records to Tree

Tags: sql, json, tree

I have a sql table similar to the one below where rowId is the primary key and parentID is the rowID of the parent record:

| RowID | ParentID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Fruit |
| 2 | 1 | Apple |
| 3 | 1 | Peach |
| 4 | 0 | Veggie |
| 5 | 4 | Corn |
| 6 | 5 | Sweet Corn |

and I need to select the data such that my result looks like:

[{"name": "Fruit", "children": [{"name": "Apple"}, {"name": "Peach"}]}, {"name": "Veggie", "children": [{"name": "Corn", "children": [{"name": "Sweet Corn"}]}]}

If anyone has any suggestions to help me thanks :)

Comment: What is your DBMS? i.e PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I am using SSMS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server try this

```
     select parent.[Name], children.Name  from Fruit parent
join Fruit children on parent.RowID = children.ParentID
for json auto
```

Comment: This is almost what I need but it only goes two level so I get: Veggies: Corn; Corrn: Sweet Corn; not Veggies: Corn: Sweet Corn.

Comment: try this SELECT
  parent.name AS [name],
  child.json AS [children]
FROM Fruit parent
cross apply (
  SELECT
    name AS [name]
  FROM Fruit child
  WHERE child.ParentID = parent.RowID 
  FOR JSON PATH
) child(json)

FOR JSON PATH

Comment: When I try that, every object that has children gets its own JSON object and I really need them in a format where children are only nested under their parents like: [{"Name": "ParentElement", "Children": [{"Name": "ChildElement", "Children": [{"Name": "grandChildElement"}] }] }] Is there a way to do this?